# Firebase integration with crashlytics without Fabric account?

Tags: java, crashlytics, google-fabric, crashlytics-android

In my old project I did all as it's described here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/upgrade-from-crash-reporting
and this: https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started

Crashlytics just works. Never bothered to create any Fabric account. However, if I try to setup new project, Firebase asks me to link with Fabric account, which was not required previously. Also, I am unable to link my old project to Fabric crashlytics, because it's shown as already linked. Hovere, I can't see Fabric in accounts settings for my project, so I cant unlink old project.

Can you clarify how does it work? Do I need Fabric account or not? Do I need to setup link Fabric -> Firebase?

[edit]

I did not even have any Fabric account, it worked without it. Just Craslytics from Firebase. Also, I did not have any Fabric api keys in my Android manifest and no Fabric plugin installed. So I opened my old project, installed Fabric plugin and added my app to Fabric (plugin has also updated my app configurarion in Android Studio).
Now my situation is as follows: after applying new configuration as described above, crashes are reported to Fabric, but not to Firebase. I am unable to link my Fabric app to Firebase, because it shows as already linked. After reverting config to old one (without any Fabric access keys), crashes are reported to Firebsse.

It looks like my project is already linked to some Fabric account, which I don't know (I have never created any, I just followed linked tutorial). Now I can't proceed with new project without creating Fabric account, which was possible some time ago.

Btw, plugin is unable to detect build flavours, once I create Fabric app for one flavour, it does not allow to create for other flavour (with other app id, so it should act as separate app). I need to create new blank project with app id that matches my flavour's app id and create Fabric app from there. As you don't allow to create new Fabric app from Fabric dashboard, this is really wtf for me.

Please anybody from Fabric support clarify all of above?

Comment: Thanks! Can you let me know if you have a Fabric account at this time? If the app never existed in Fabric then you should select that in the onboarding flow for Crashlytics. Can you update your question with a screenshot of what you see when you go to the Crashlytics tab in Firebase? Thanks!

Comment: Question updated.

Comment: Hi, Paul from Crashlytics here. Could you please contact support(at)fabric(dot)io with your package name and a link to this question? Happy to help you debug this further there.